# Fourier-restriction on Hyperplane

Tags: harmonic-analysis, fourier-restriction

In Muscalu, Schlag "Classical and multilinear harmonic analysis, Volume 1" (2013), Excercise 11.1 is to prove, basically, that there exists a function $f\in L^p \quad \forall\ p>1$ such, that the Fourier-transform $\mathcal{F}f$ of $f$ is infinite on a (previously chosen) hyperplane
$$H(\theta, s) := \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n | x\cdot \theta = s\} \qquad (\theta \in S^{n-1}, s\in \mathbb{R})$$
I have arrived at the function
$$f_{\theta, s}(x) =\frac{1}{1+|x\cdot \theta -s|}$$
(the $\cdot$ denotes the standard inner product) I could show, that $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \quad \forall\ p>1$, but I have failed to show, that it's Fourier-transform is identical to $\infty$ on $H(\theta,s)$.
How can I show this?

The hint which lead me to this choice of $f_{\theta,s}$ is from this book: [Fourier Analysis And Convexity, p. 218](http://books.google.com/books?id=lJMTwTeKDJcC&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218#v=onepage&q&f=false)

**EDIT**:
Thanks to @paulgarret I was able to prove the following
Let $U$ be a unitary matrix with $U\theta = e_n$ and let
$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} x_j^2}}{1+|x_n|}$$
Then by $f_{\theta, s} := f(Ux-se_n)$ we have
$$\widehat{f_{\theta,s}}(\xi) =\infty \quad \forall \ \xi \in H(\theta,s)$$
and
$$\Vert f_{\theta,s} \Vert_p^p = \Vert f \Vert_p^p = \frac{2}{p-1} \left ( \frac{\pi}{p} \right ) ^{\frac{n-1}{2}} < \infty \qquad \forall \ p>1$$
The only remaining Question is, how can we construct such a $U$ to give a concrete example?

Comment: I doubt that $f_{\theta, s}$ is in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Take for example $\theta=(0\ldots 1)$ and $s=0$. Then $$f_{\theta, s}(x_1\ldots x_n)=\frac{1}{1+\lvert x_n\rvert}$$ and $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(\frac{1}{1+\lvert x_n\rvert}\right)^p dx_1\ldots dx_n=\int dx_2\ldots dx_n \int \left(\frac{1}{1+|x_n|}\right)^p dx_1=\infty.$$

Comment: Please take a closer look. $p>1$ works out just fine; I arrive at $$\Vert f\Vert_p^p = \frac{2}{p-1}$$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Here's my calculation:
$$\Vert f \Vert_p^p = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)|^p dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{H(\theta,t)} |f(x)|^p dS(x) dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{H(\theta,t)} \frac{1}{(1+|t-s|)^p} dS(x) dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{(1+|t-s|)^p} dt = 2\int_s^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+t-s)^p} dt = 2\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{u^p} du = \frac{2}{p-1} \qquad \forall\ p>1$$

Comment: @GiueseppeNegro's point is that your proposed function is constant in $n-1$ out of $n$ directions, so its integral (or any power) diverges, much as $\int_{\mathbb R^2}{dx\,dy\over 1+x^2}$ diverges. Thus, you need to do something in those $n-1$ other directions to arrange convergence.

Comment: @paulgarrett I cannot see the problem here, plus the "authority argument" from the reference book.

Comment: Hey, isn't the Fourier transform separable? How does that choice give you an infinite F.T. anywhere? (since F.T. of Gaussian is also Gaussian up to exponent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write a preliminary answer as expanded comment, to explain why the tentative answer has a certain problem, although it does make progress: first, a simpler analogue where a function is constant in one direction: take $f(x,y)={1\over 1+x^2}$. Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y)\;dx\,dy\;=\; \int_{\mathbb R^2}{dx\,dy\over 1+x^2}
\;=\;\int_{\mathbb R} {dx\over 1+x^2}\cdot \int_{\mathbb R}1\;dy
$$
The integral over $x$ is fine, but the integral in $y$ is the integral of $1$ over the whole real line, giving $+\infty$. Thus, as in your attempt, as noted by @GiuseppeNegro, this glitch has to be addressed.

By rotation, we might as well suppose the hyperplane is the $x_n=0$ hyperplane. Thus, you want a function to blow up as $x_n\to 0$, but/and be integrable on the whole $\mathbb R^n$. Ok, as a function of $x_n$, something like ${1\over \sqrt{|x_n|}(1+x_n^2)}$. In $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$, you want reasonable behavior, so a Gaussian (handy for FT, also) like $e^{-\pi(x_1^2+\ldots+x_{n-1}^2)}$ would do. The product has the right sort of behavior. Take FT, ...

(Although one should generally *tend* to believe "authorities", there is the auxiliary issue of being alert to disconnects between one's understanding of what is being asserted/asked, what is really asked/asserted, and, still, what one has actually done. Partial but incomplete progress should not be confused with "failure", nor with "success", for example.)

Comment: Okay, thanks a bunch; I'll go for $$f(x) = \frac{e^{-(x_1^2 + \ldots + x_{n-1}^2)}}{1+|x_n|}$$ for the moment and see where it takes me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting idea, for two dimensions, and I'm sure it can be generalized. Let $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\log |x| (1 + |yx|)}$. This function is in $L^p$: $\int |f(x,y)|^p dy dx = \int \frac{1}{(\log |x|)^p} \int \frac{du}{|x|(1+|u|)^p} dx < \infty$, and just barely (needs $p>1$ for the logarithm)!

Now take the Fourier transform. Integrating in $y$ first is already divergent (though I'm not sure about being $\infty$. The F.T. seems to exist as a principal value). It's not very clear here. If $\xi = 0$ then we definitely have $\infty$, but in other places the function is not Lebesgue integrable, so I don't know what to make of it.

To generalize this specific example, maybe
$f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n) = \frac{1}{\log r (1+|x_n| r_{}^{n-1})}$ where $r= \sqrt{ |x_1|^2 + \ldots + |x_{n-1}|^2}$

Comment: Thank you, but the function specified above seems alot handier for these purposes, as the gaussian
$$\sqrt{\pi} = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2} dx$$
Is also very nice for FT. That $\mathcal{F}f \in L^q$ need not be checked, as $\mathcal{F} : L^p \to L^q$ is known to be continuous.

Comment: Ohh the FT there is already not convergent I see now.  Also to construct the U take first column to be theta  then arbitrarily extend to a basis and use orthogonalization (keep theta as one of the directions)

Comment: Actually figured that out myself^^ though, because $U\theta = e_n$, we need to pick the last row / column to be $\theta$ ;-)

Comment: so does it make a difference that the value is not infinity (just undefined)? seems only infinite at the origin

Comment: What I need is, that $\mathcal{F}f$ cannot be restricted to a bounded subset $S$ of a Hyperplane. This means, that we need $\mathcal{F}f$ to be such a function, that the restriction
$$\left.\mathcal{F}f\right |_S$$
is not well-defined (or $\Vert \left . \mathcal{F}f \right |_S \Vert_1 = \infty$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}f \notin L^1(S)$)